# virtual machine manager gui "Please specify a valid OS variant"

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

When creating a VM, this error appears: `"Please specify a valid OS variant"` and I don't know why, it's coming from the OS type section, how do I fix this?

Edit: i found a different way to make a VM, which is change the architecture from arm64 to x86_64, but for this question, I'm using the arm64 architecture, i still wanna make a vm with it.

I'm using qemu (my machine doesn't support kvm) host operating system is Ubuntu MATE, error is shown while making a VM, and the VM doesn't boot

Edit 2: when using the ARM architecture, it limits my only options on
installing Operating systems to just "import existing disk image", not even "local install media" which I wanted!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question and give us some details. What is the host operating system? What VM tool are you using? When exactly is this error shown? Is the VM booting? The more detail you give us, the more we will be able to help you.

Comment: @terdon Hi. I'm using qemu (my machine doesn't support kvm) host operating system is Ubuntu MATE, error is shown while making a VM, and the VM doesn't boot.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and add these details. Clarify exactly when you get the error, at what point of the VM creation process, maybe include a screenshot, and show us what settings you have chosen.

Comment: Still unclear to me how you reach this step. Are you using directly the `qemu` command on a shell? In such case what are the options? Are you actually using libvirt through the GUI `virt-manager`? etc.

Comment: @A.B No, I'm not using the terminal, yes, I'm using virt-manager and I don't know whether I'm using libvirt

Comment: virt-manager is a client of libvirt, so yes you are using libvirt. In turn libvirt uses QEMU as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its Two points here:

- quemu does not yet have its own aarch64/arm Bios/uefi implemented yet, so you will need your own.
  The way most arm chip (based computers) run is very different and as such qemu will probably take time on that. There is a project which created a suitable bios, but you would have to compile it and its programming language yourself all designed to be compiled on x86_64 architecture (can be done on arm, but I want to keep this post clear of too much winging). in most cases its easier to run architecture which has the Bios/uefi built-into quemu.
- To the second point is that when you are setting VM then when choosing an image or creating a drive the virt-manager gives you a box to chose operating system you are installing/setting and based on that it will assign basic resources, so you only have to chose the ones you wish to adjust and the rest are assigned automatically.

Alternative to be considered: if you only intending to run terminal (I am not sure if there are any arm based boards strong enough to run xorg under vm reliaby) apps under same architecture, chrooting might be better for you. [What chrooting is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

Alternatively you can do what I do and have three sd cards and all of them mounted mine main users directory from external hard-drive, so mine projects are shared

Comment: The first point I don't know whether my version of qemu has it built in, but the second point is sorta off since i didn't add enough information, Oops!

Comment: I do not think it does have arm64 bios. Neither of mine distros had it last month, and bios is a very big (exceptionaly skilled) project where month is nothing.
SO you still havent said anithing regards chrooting. I often chroot from Manjaro to ubuntu, to use CLI packages it has but Majnjaro doesn't, which gives you far greater speeds then virtualizing hole mashines with fraction of the work and easier sharing of data

Comment: Not entirely sure what chrooting even means, but i don't use manjaro or ubuntu (or atleast i think ubuntu MATE isn't technically ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu mate is an Ubuntu, but with ubuntus weakest link (Unity) removed.
You may want to look chrooting up. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot
In simple terms chrooting is a case of changing a place where root points. meaning that everything inside is in a form of jail, with no access outside (every jail can be broken out by some smart-ass). Because  most processes can only see and access down-to your new root points. Its a lot faster as you only have one kernel running. Its used a lot for developenment and security. For Installations, package building server runs....

Comment: More about what Chroot is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot
More oldschool advanced chrooting guide: https://bartsimons.me/ubuntu-linux-chroot-guide/